# Почему такие функции-члены являются виртуальными?

Tags: c++, разработка-игр, virtual, движок

В CryEngine определен класс, который предоставляет интерфейс для сущности (объекта/актора) который размещен на уровне

Дело в том, что есть функция-член `virtual const char* GetName() = 0;`

У меня один вопрос зачем она виртуальная? Ведь мы просто хотим получить имя сущности в сцене? Какой смысл делать вообще подобные вещи виртуальными? Ведь просто получить `const char*` же

Так же есть и сеттер `virtual void SetName(const char* name) = 0;`, тоже непонятно

Comment: Вас, наверное, удивит, но эта функция вообще отсутствует — вернее, она не имеет тела, так что объект такого *абстрактного* класса вы не создадите.

Зато у вас может быть масса *конкретных* наследников этого класса, и у каждого это имя может вычисляться/возвращаться по-разному. А главное — со всеми создаваемыми объектами *разных* классов можно работать через ссылку/указатель на один абстрактный класс. Если бы функция была не виртуальна, надо было бы очень точно указывать каждый класс еще на этапе компиляции, их нельзя бы было обрабатывать, грубо говоря, одним циклом.

Comment: Словом, читайте, что такое наследование и полимирфизм, а равно что такое абстрактный класс.

Comment: Слушаю вас! "И незачем так кричать, я вас и так прекрасно слышу..." (с) :)

Comment: *"Ведь просто получить const char* же"* - это именно то, что делает эта функция. ¿Вы же осознаете, что `virtual`  не относится к `const char *`?

Comment: @user7860670 Судя по "есть функция-член ... зачем **она** виртуальная" — да, осознает.